# I want to make list of variables A1 to A20 using loop in r

Tags: r

I am new to R and would love to get some help

```
s=list()
for (i in 1:20){
  name=paste("A",i,sep="")
  s[name]=Ai
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop.  `s <- vector("list", 20); names(s) <- paste0("A", 1:20)`.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `s[name]=Ai`.  Also, you access an individual element of a list with `[[` (or `$`), not `[`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `length` and `names`:

```r
s <- list()
length(s) <- 20
names(s) <- paste0("A", 1:20)

s
```